# Export DBML to SQL script

Tags: .net, sql, sql-server, linq, linq-to-sql

Due to a harddrive crash, I lost my SQL server database files for a project I was creating.

I still have my DBML files I used in my .NET project, so I still have the database structure in a file.

Is it possible to export my DBML somehow to a SQL server script, to recreate my databases in SQL server.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How to: Dynamically Create a Database (LINQ to SQL)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399420.aspx