# DataContext to DB

Tags: c#, .net, sql, linq

I have designed my DB using the ORM in VS 2008.

What is the best way to export this to an SQL server so it will create the tables and relations on SQL Server?

Thanks,

JD

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using the LINQ-to-SQL, then:

```
var(dc = new MyDataContext()) {
    dc.CreateDatabase();
}
```

should do it, but **only** if you have **all** the required data. To be honest, it works better starting from tables (perhaps in SSMS) and dragging them *into* LINQ-to-SQL.

Also; there are a lot of important database concepts (indexing, etc) that is *not* expressed in DBML.

Answer (score 1):

See: [Export DBML to SQL script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/903922/export-dbml-to-sql-script/903964#903964)

Comment: I took the liberty of assuming you meant the LINQ to SQL ORM rather than LINQ to Entities.

Comment: @RobS - Right you are - woops, totally wrong terminology there!

Comment: Perception wise, there isn't much difference between "Entity Framework" and "Linq To Entities".